# How to save data in database

Tags: php, database, mysqli, sql-update

Please refer code below. I'm using phpMyAdmin to store my data in xampp(as my server). I found this code and add into my website. My question is; how to save the result in database. Anyone??

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Geo City Locator by geoip-db.com</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>Country: <span id="country"></span></div>
    <div>State: <span id="state"></span></div>
    <div>City: <span id="city"></span></div>
    <div>Postal: <span id="postal"></span></div>
    <div>Latitude: <span id="latitude"></span></div>
    <div>Longitude: <span id="longitude"></span></div>
    <div>IP address: <span id="ipv4"></span></div>                             
</body>
<script>

    var country = document.getElementById('country');
    var state = document.getElementById('state');
    var city = document.getElementById('city');
    var postal = document.getElementById('postal');
    var latitude = document.getElementById('latitude');
    var longitude = document.getElementById('longitude');
    var ip = document.getElementById('ipv4');

    function callback(data)
    {
        country.innerHTML = data.country_name;
        state.innerHTML = data.state;
        city.innerHTML = data.city;
        postal.innerHTML = data.postal;
        latitude.innerHTML = data.latitude;
        longitude.innerHTML = data.longitude;
        ip.innerHTML = data.IPv4;
    }

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://geoip-db.com/json/geoip.php?jsonp=callback';
    var h = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    h.parentNode.insertBefore(script, h);

</script> 
</html>
```

Comment: where's your database code?

Comment: i dont have, because i dont know how to store into database @MasivuyeCokile or do you have any examples

Comment: Read the answer bellow first, try to do the examples in the link then come back when you don't understand anything.

Comment: okay. tq @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: There are literally thousands of tutorials out there about this.

Comment: can you give me the link or else @MagnusEriksson

Comment: 1. I won't google it for you. Google is easy to use. Give it a shot. 2. You have an answer _with_ a link (even though asking for off-site resources and tutorials are off topic for SO).

Answer (score 5):

In order to "talk" with your database (for inserting, deleting, updating or creating) you'll need to use an SQL library, PDO or MySQLi.
I suggest you use PDO, read more here: https://phpdelusions.net/pdo

Answer (score 0):

You must learn database commands. Update, delete, select etc. You can do everything for db after that. And you can search `update database` or `mysqli update`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use sql queries for inserting the data into database. You can start with CRUD Operations for learning. For your current code i am suggesting you to use ajax with jquery to submit data into the database. Alternatively you can also use core php to save data into database.